# Database schema for event ticketing system

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to figure out a good way to build a database for events. I have a client that has a list of customer names and promo codes. A customer on the list can go to a landing page, fill out the promo code and choose an event from a drop down field they would like to attend. He currently has 4 events ready to go.

In the database, should I create 4 tables, one for each event with customers or separate the customers from the event tables (ie...customer table and 4 event tables). There might be more events in the future so scalable options would be preferred.

Also, each customer is only aloud a maximum number of 4 tickets and they can only use the promo code once.

Thanks!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jay is correct that a complete answer would be quite long, but I'll offer a few starting pointers nonetheless as it sounds like you're quite new to database architecture.

As a general principle, you should never build a schema that involves adding/removing tables at run time. The relationship you're looking for between customers and events is many-to-many, which in MySQL would use a junction table. An example schema would look like this:

- customer

  - customer_id (primary key)
  - email, name, etc.
- event

  - event_id (primary key)
  - name, time, etc.
- ticket

  - ticket_id (primary key)
  - customer_id (index)
  - event_id (index)
  - date_purchased, etc.

Rules like "each customer is only allowed 4 tickets" should be implemented at a code level rather than a schema level since that is subject to change and your schema should be flexible enough to accommodate that change, tempting as it may be to have four columns in the customers table for the four tickets.

To get the events that customer ID 1 is attending:

```
SELECT DISTINCT event.*
FROM ticket
LEFT JOIN event ON ticket.event_id = event.event_id
WHERE ticket.customer_id = 1
```

To get the customers attending event ID 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer.*
FROM ticket
LEFT JOIN customer ON ticket.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE ticket.event_id = 1
```

A common format for junction tables is to combine the two table names, as in `event_customer`, but in this case calling it `ticket` makes more sense, since you might be including additional information about the ticket purchase in that table.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great starting point.